# Tableau Date Filter across multiple tables

Tags: tableau-api

I have multiple tables within Tableau. Each table has its own start and end date. How can I create one start and one end date filter that will be applied to each of the tables?
Table 1 Start End
Table 2 Start End
Table 3 Start End
I need one global start date filter and one global end date filter that can filter

```
  (
    Table1.EndDate >= <selected start date filter> 
    OR 
    (
      Table1.EndDate] IS NULL 
      AND Table1.StartDate <= <selected start date filter> 
    )
  )
  AND 
  (
    Table2.EndDate >= <selected start date filter> 
    OR 
    (
      Table2.EndDate] IS NULL 
      AND Table2.StartDate <= <selected start date filter> 
    )
  )
  AND 
  (
    Table3.EndDate >= <selected start date filter> 
    OR 
    (
      Table3.EndDate] IS NULL 
      AND Table3.StartDate <= <selected start date filter> 
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Join the tables together into one data source then create the date filter

Comment: Each table has its own dates specific to the data in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Parameters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm), this sounds like a good case for parameters to solve.